# access elements inside ListComponent in JasperReports API (version 5.6.1)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have designed a jrxml report which takes a list of beans as datasource. Depending on the size of the list, I want to change the appearance of the report. In my understanding, it is only possible using the JasperReports API by manipulating the compiled JasperReport object.

For changing the column witdths, i need to access elements inside a List component. For elements outside of the List component it works like this:

```
JasperReport jasperReport =     jasperCompileManager.compileReport(detailReportTemplate.getInputStream());
// access element inside the ColumnHeader
JRElement ch0 = jasperReport.getColumnHeader().getElementByKey("ColumnHeader0");
// access the list
JRBaseComponentElement list = (JRBaseComponentElement) jasperReport.getDetailSection().getBands()[0].getElementByKey("DetailList");
```

the above works, but i dont know how to access elements inside the list. searching inside the band returns "null" for chlid elements:

```
JRElement cv0 = jasperReport.getDetailSection().getBands()[0].getElementByKey("ColumnValue0");
```

my jrxml snipplet:

```
<jasperReport>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="62" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="ColumnHeader0" x="425" y="41" width="100" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{SPF_ITEM_LIST}.size() > 2]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[...]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        ...
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="DetailList" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" />
            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                ...
                <jr:listContents height="20" width="555">
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                        <reportElement key="ColumnValue0" style="zebra" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="225" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[...]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </jr:listContents>
            </jr:list>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Is there a way accessing the children of a list component by key or other means? if not, what component could i use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by getting rid of the list component. Instead i just use textfields directly in the detail band. This allows me to lookup these fields with getElementByKey(), and leads to a much simpler jrxml as well.

Answer (score 0):

In jasper, maybe it is easier to create a boolean, and depending of that boolean you can print a subreport or another.

```
 boolean visible = myList.size() > 50;
```

and in the property "print when expression" put that boolean.

Comment: I am already doing this! columns are only displayed when the printWhenExpression evaluates to 'true'. what i want to do additionally, is to adjust column widths according to the size of the list.